# how to use nohup with R script, and redirecting any save command to my local folder

Tags: r, save, nohup

I want to use nohup to run my script in R, but inside my script I usually save the variable in my local folder, moreover, I also want to redirect anywarning messages to my local folder as well, when I tried to use nohup command it usually doesn't save my variables when I call the save command in my R script, so is there a way to do so?
thanks

Comment: Make a tiny example script (two lines?), share it with us, then show us how you run it.

Comment: Particularly, show us in the minimal reproducible example that save does not work.

Comment: I tried to run the following code:
x=5
save(x, file=paste(myFile,"x.RData",sep=''))


and the following line is how I run it 
nohup Rscript test.R&

but I don't see the variable x in my directory